# How do I translate this sql-injection-susceptible function to a prepared function in MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I have two functions which are sql-injection-susceptible, I have managed to translate the first one into a prepared function but I'm failing to see how I would translate the second one. This is the original first one:

```
    function modify($sql, &$id)
    {
        $link = database_link();

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        $insertId = mysqli_insert_id($link);

        return mysqli_affected_rows($link);
    }
```

Which I translated to:

```
    function preparedModify($sql, $types, &$insertId, ...$value)
    {
        $statement = mysqli_prepare(database_link(), $sql);

        $statement->bind_param($types, ...$value);

        $statement->execute();

        $insertId = $statement->insert_id;

        return $statement->affected_rows;
    }
```

Which worked and I'm happy with. This is my second function that needs to be translated:

```
    function select($sql, &$rows)
    {

        $link = database_link();

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        $rows = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        return mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
```

Which is totally unclear to me how I would translate it as a beginner. Could you help me while at the same time breaking down your answer(s) to point out what the strategy behind your translation is? Because my strategy for the first function was just googling for alternative functions and that way I managed to do the first one but I reached nowhere with the second one using the same approach.

Comment: What is your particular problem? Why can't at last start the same way as in the other function - with ...$value stuff?

Comment: @YourCommonSense That part I figured out indeed, just the way I would do the part with the array `$rows` that I haven't managed and still unclear to me.

Comment: Note that this would still be susceptible to SQL injection if the SQL itself can be tampered with.  Moving it to a prepared statement protects injection from the variables but you still need to ensure that the SQL is trusted.

Comment: @Egret can u give a small example demonstrating what you mean, please?

Comment: The sql itself is passed in as a variable so we can't tell from the code snippet what it's source is.  If it was passed in from an untrusted source (a client) or if it was created with concatenation with strings from an untrusted source that would still leave you vulnerable to SQL inj - even if you use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `mysqlnd` installed (to allow use of [`mysqli_stmt::get_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)), the changes can be fairly simple. The first part is the same as `preparedModify`, then we just use a call to `get_result` and the rest of the function remains the same:

```
function preparedSelect($sql, $types, &$rows, ...$value)
{
    $statement = mysqli_prepare(database_link(), $sql);

    $statement->bind_param($types, ...$value);

    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->get_result();

    $rows = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    return $statement->num_rows;
}
```

As has been commented, you don't need the loop to generate `$rows`, you can simply use `mysqli_result::fetch_all`:

```
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Again this requires the native `mysqlnd` driver to be installed.

Comment: May I ask why did you choose to use `num_rows` instead of `affected_rows`?

Comment: @Doesitmatter `affected_rows` is for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries. `num_rows` is for `SELECT` queries.

Comment: You don't need the while loop. You can just fetchAll records and return.

Comment: @Doesitmatter a `SELECT` query shouldn't have a `VALUES` clause... that's why the `prepare` failed.

Comment: @Doesitmatter also a REGEXP expression placeholder shouldn't be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a quirk, I have to admit, with running prepared SELECT queries, as you cannot just fetch a familiar array right from the statement so you will need an additional function call, `get_result()`. But at least you could have started the same way as with the other function as it is the correct way to run a function with prepared statements.

A couple other things to note

- I suppose that `database_link()` creates a new database connection every time it is called. It should never be this way, a connection must be created only once. Therefore create it first and then pass the `$link` variable into all your function calls.
- returning a function's result through a parameter is ugly and unreadable and for these reasons is frowned upon. And you don't have to return the row count - it just makes no sense as you can always use `count($rows)` to get the count.
- it is highly inconvenient to put separate variables into the function call, I learned it the hard way. Instead, put them in the form of array. This way you will be able to either have separate variables or a single variable that already contains all the data required.

Given all that we can create a procedure that is easy to use and read, based on my [Mysqli helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple):

```
function select($link, $sql, $values = [], $types = '')
{
    if (!$values) {
        $result = $link->query($sql);
    } else {
        $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($values));
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
    }
    return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);   
}

$link = database_link();
$rows = select($link, "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary > ?", [$gross]);
if ($rows) {
    // you don't actually need even a count() call
}
```